# Why does int 3 causes general protection fault?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, operating-system, osdev

I am having trouble with the lab from the course MIT 6.828.

The lab notes ask me to write a handler for `debug breakpoint`, corresponding to trap number 3. In the codes provided by the lab, there is inline assembly causing the interrupt directly like this:

```c
void
umain(int argc, char **argv)
{
    asm volatile("int $3");
}
```

The code is compiled as `int3` instruction without surprises, as the disassembly code shows.

When I run it, the trap frame generated shows that it caused an interrupt with number `13`, general protection fault, rather than `3`, which is confusing. Other kinds of interrupts share no such a problem when testing.

Please kindly explain how general protection fault may be triggered, and why.

Comment: That the compiler compiles "`int $3`" as "`int3`" is not as obvious as you think: There are two (very special) cases where the two instructions `int $3` = `0xCD 03` and `int3` = `0xCC` behave a bit differently; therefore, some compilers distinguish between the two instructions!

Comment: What does "*Other kinds of interrupts share no such a problem when testing.*" mean? Did you write a handler for some interrupt > 0x30 (for example for "`int 0x35`") and the `int 0x35` instruction entered your interrupt?

Comment: Does it actually disassemble as `int3` or `int $3`? The difference is that the first one is one byte and the second one is two bytes.

Comment: The Intel SDM vol 2 lists all the possible reasons that an INT instruction can cause #GP.

Comment: Is it possible that it calls the int3 handler correctly and the #GP is caused by the IRET?

Comment: Run or single-step your program in an emulator like BOCHS that will let you pinpoint exactly what led to the #GP.

Comment: It was my fault. I set the handler only to accept kernel mode entrance. Got to take a closer look at the manuals.

Comment: The disassembly is `int3`, not `int $3`. `int $3` is written as inline assembly among C code. I am using `gcc`, referencing to the GNU assembler manual.

Comment: I am using `qemu`&`gdb` as dev tools. Thank you for your interest in my questions. Another question presents itself, though. How is a breakpoint in `gdb` not invoking any of these interrupt. I'd best look closer into `qemu` debug mechanism.

Comment: How are you running the code? I mean, in what environment? If you run that code on a modern OS you won't get an #DB unless there's a debugger attached, I think. Then again, being asked to write a handler either means you are running under a specialized environment or they meant a signal handler (in which case the interrupt number is irrelevant).

Comment: I am trying to complete the lab of MIT's OS course. This is a primitive operating system assignment for learning operating system theories.

Comment: I decided to take a peek at the xv6 code and I may not be far off the mark. In [`trap.c`](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/trap.c) all the IDT entries are set with a DPL of 0 as a default and then in the case of `T_SYSCALL` that is changed. After the SETGATE is done for `T_SYSCALL` add a line like this and see what happens `SETGATE(idt[T_BRKPT], 0, SEG_KCODE<<3, vectors[T_BRKPT], DPL_USER);` . After this it should not #GP if the `int3` is done from user mode (ring 3)